# How do I setup unison to sync a folder one way

Tags: linux, debian, rsync, synchronization, unison

I have a 1tb NAS that has a 1tb usb external hard attached

I have prepared the file system on the usb disk and mounted it

I want to 100% sync my data from my nas to the usb disk - but I want it to be incremental and only have the NAS as the 'master' - eg if a file changes on the usb external hard drive I want it to ignore this change as its not the live version (not that I think the files will change on the usb disk but im paranoid the live could get overwritten)

Also if a file gets deleted on live I want to retain the deleted file on the usb disk

Can unison sync one-way and achive the above for me? if so with simply

```
unison sorce/ target/
```

Work?

Thanks
Rob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't use Unison in this case, since its main purpose is the two way sync. Plain old [`rsync`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/rsync) will do the job here. This will synchronise files from the source to the destination without deleting files on the destination (although it will overwrite files on the destination to be the same as on the source).

```
rsync --recursive --times --verbose source/ destination/
```

Comment: I have run a cp -a source/ destination/ to start with - once thats done I will run your command (I had trouble with rsync - found it didnt copy all the data)